# Numerical integral for complicated Bessel function

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I want to evaluate the complicated infinite integral including Bessel function.

```
a = 0.5; b = 1; r1 = 5;
\[Kappa] = Sqrt[b/a]; 
u1[r_, t_] := 
 NIntegrate[(1 - Exp[-b*t*w^2/a])/w^2*(
   A1[r, w]*B1[w] + A2[r, w]*B2[w])/(B1[w]^2 + B2[w]^2), {w, 0, 
   Infinity}, 
  Method -> {"LevinRule", "LevinFunctions" -> {BesselJ, BesselY}}];
u2[r_, t_] := 
  NIntegrate[(1 - Exp[-b*t*w^2/a])/w^2*(
    BesselY[0, \[Kappa]*r*w]*B1[w] + BesselJ[0, \[Kappa]*r*w]*B2[w])/(
    B1[w]^2 + B2[w]^2), {w, 0, Infinity}, 
   Method -> {"LevinRule", "LevinFunctions" -> {BesselJ, BesselY}}];
A1[r_, w_] := 
  BesselJ[1, r1*w]*BesselY[0, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*BesselY[0, r*w] - 
   BesselY[1, r1*w]*BesselY[0, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*BesselJ[0, r*w] - 
   Sqrt[a*b]*(BesselJ[0, r1*w]*BesselY[1, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*
       BesselY[0, r*w] - 
      BesselY[0, r1*w]*BesselY[1, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*BesselJ[0, r*w]);
A2[r_, w_] := 
  BesselY[1, r1*w]*BesselJ[0, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*BesselJ[0, r*w] - 
   BesselJ[1, r1*w]*BesselJ[0, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*BesselY[0, r*w] - 
   Sqrt[a*b]*(BesselY[0, r1*w]*BesselJ[1, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*
       BesselJ[0, r*w] - 
      BesselJ[0, r1*w]*BesselJ[1, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*BesselY[0, r*w]);
B1[w_] := 
  BesselJ[1, r1*w]*BesselJ[0, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*BesselY[1, w] - 
   BesselY[1, r1*w]*BesselJ[0, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*BesselJ[1, w] - 
   Sqrt[a*b]*(BesselJ[0, r1*w]*BesselJ[1, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*
       BesselY[1, w] - 
      BesselY[0, r1*w]*BesselJ[1, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*BesselJ[1, w]);
B2[w_] := 
  BesselJ[1, r1*w]*BesselY[0, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*BesselY[1, w] - 
   BesselY[1, r1*w]*BesselY[0, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*BesselJ[1, w] - 
   Sqrt[a*b]*(BesselJ[0, r1*w]*BesselY[1, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*
       BesselY[1, w] - 
      BesselY[0, r1*w]*BesselY[1, \[Kappa]*r1*w]*BesselJ[1, w]);
```

where u1 is in 0-r1, and u2 is in r1-infinity

I am trying to evaluate the u1 and u2 function at specific point

```
u1[1, 10]
u1[r1 + 1, 10]
```

however, the error message is shown as

> NIntegrate::levmaxord: (BesselJ[0,7.07107 w] BesselJ[1,5 w]
>   BesselY[1,w]-0.707107 (-BesselJ[1,w] BesselJ[1,7.07107 w] BesselY[0,5
>   w]+BesselJ[0,5 w] BesselJ[1,7.07107 w] BesselY[1,w])-BesselJ[0,7.07107
>   w] BesselJ[1,w] BesselY[1,5 w]) (BesselJ[1,5 w] BesselY[0,w]
>   BesselY[0,7.07107 w]-<<1>>-0.707107 (BesselJ[0,5 w] <<1>>
>   <<1>>-<<1>>)) is a Levin function of differential order 1088 which
>   exceeds value of option "MaxOrder" -> 50. Treating (BesselJ[0,7.07107
>   w] BesselJ[1,5 w] BesselY[1,w]-0.707107 (-BesselJ[1,w]
>   BesselJ[1,7.07107 w] BesselY[0,5 w]+BesselJ[0,5 w] BesselJ[1,7.07107
>   w] BesselY[1,w])-BesselJ[0,7.07107 w] BesselJ[1,w] BesselY[1,5 w])
>   (BesselJ[1,5 w] BesselY[0,w] BesselY[0,7.07107 w]-<<1>>-0.707107
>   (BesselJ[0,5 w] <<1>> <<1>>-<<1>>)) as a non-Levin function. >>
>
> NIntegrate::levmaxord: (-BesselJ[0,7.07107 w] BesselJ[1,5 w]
>   BesselY[0,w]-0.707107 (-BesselJ[0,5 w] BesselJ[1,7.07107 w]
>   BesselY[0,w]+BesselJ[0,w] BesselJ[1,7.07107 w] BesselY[0,5
>   w])+BesselJ[0,w] BesselJ[0,7.07107 w] BesselY[1,5 w]) (BesselJ[1,5 w]
>   BesselY[0,7.07107 w] BesselY[1,w]-<<1>>-0.707107 (-BesselJ[1,w] <<1>>
>   <<1>>+<<1>>)) is a Levin function of differential order 1088 which
>   exceeds value of option "MaxOrder" -> 50. Treating (-BesselJ[0,7.07107
>   w] BesselJ[1,5 w] BesselY[0,w]-0.707107 (-BesselJ[0,5 w]
>   BesselJ[1,7.07107 w] BesselY[0,w]+BesselJ[0,w] BesselJ[1,7.07107 w]
>   BesselY[0,5 w])+BesselJ[0,w] BesselJ[0,7.07107 w] BesselY[1,5 w])
>   (BesselJ[1,5 w] BesselY[0,7.07107 w] BesselY[1,w]-<<1>>-0.707107
>   (-BesselJ[1,w] <<1>> <<1>>+<<1>>)) as a non-Levin function. >>
>
> NIntegrate::nonlev: Integrand ((1-E^(-20. w^2)) (<<1>>))/(w^2
>   ((<<1>>)^2+(<<1>>)^2)) is not a Levin function. >>
>
> NIntegrate::mtdfb: Numerical integration with LevinRule failed. The
>   integration continues with Method -> GaussKronrodRule. >>

How can I evaluate the value of u1 and u2 right?

Comment: I use u1[1, 10] to evaluate a value.

Comment: my bad. Lets try this again. Wrap your integrand in `Simplify`. Make `a=1/2`. Then you get a message indicating you need to increase "MaxOrder". With `"MaxOrder"->512` it is running without error but taking a long time . Progress I suppose..

Comment: Do you mean rewrite the code as <Method -> {"LevinRule", "LevinFunctions" -> {BesselJ, BesselY},"MaxOrder"->512}>?

Comment: Thank you. But it take lots of time. Need more efficiency way.

Comment: I would guess you need to use a different method.  You maybe want to revise the question or ask a new one since we know how to deal with the  the particular error shown.